# How to set state in useEffect hook using React and Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to change right property from 16px to 40px when user is in page "/items/:itemId" using React and Typescript.

Below is my component snippet,

```
const root = () => {
    <PopupContextProvider>
        <App/>
    </PopupContextProvider>
}


export const PopupContextProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    return (
        <popupContext.Provider value={context}>
            {children}
                {(condition1 || condition2) && (
                    <Popup onHide={dismiss} />
                )}
        </popupContext.Provider>
    );
}


export function Popup({ onHide }: Props) {
    return (
        <Dialog>
            <DialogBody>
                <span>Title</span>
                <Description/>
            </DialogBody>
            <Actions>
                <span>Hide</span>
            </Actions>
        </Dialog>
    );
}


const Dialog = styled.div`
    position: fixed;
    right: 16px;//want to change this to 40px if user is in page 
    "/items/:itemId"
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
`;
```

**What I have tried?**

```
export function Popup({ onHide }: Props) {
    const location = useLocation();
    const [isView, setIsView] = React.useState(false);
    if (location.pathname === '/items/:itemId') {
        setIsView(true);
        //Here, it doesn't change to true.
        //How can I do the same in useEffect or something that updates
    }
    return (
        <Dialog isView={isView}>
            <DialogBody>
                <span>Title</span>
                <Description/>
            </DialogBody>
            <Actions>
                <span>Hide</span>
            </Actions>
        </Dialog>
    );
}


const Dialog = styled.div<isView?:boolean>`
    position: fixed;
    ${({ isView }) => isView && 'right:  40px;'}
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
`;
```

My above code doesn't update the position of the popup with right 40px even though user is in page "/items/:itemId".

I am not sure what is going wrong. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

what i have tried based on one of the answer provided.

```
export function Popup({ onHide }: Props) {
    const location = useLocation();
    const [isView, setIsView] = React.useState(false);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const match = matchPath(
            location.pathname,
            '/items/:itemId'
        );
        if (match) { //it doesnt get it into this condition since match is 
            //null
            setIsScheduleView(true);
        }
    }, []);
    return (
        <Dialog isView={isView}>
            <DialogBody>
                <span>Title</span>
                <Description/>
            </DialogBody>
            <Actions>
                <span>Hide</span>
            </Actions>
        </Dialog>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you are using react router, if so you can use `matchPath` https://reactrouter.com/web/api/matchPath

```
import { matchPath } from 'react-router';

setIsView(
 !!matchPath(
    this.props.location.pathname, 
    {path: 'items/:itemId'}
  ));
```

Comment: thanks. but this gives me an error Uncaught Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Comment: i have used it in useeffect like in my edited question and still the state isView is false.

Comment: i was logging match in useeffect and i dont see it printed in log except only once when popup is mounted and is in other url initially.

Comment: I updated my answer with the most recent implementation of matchPath, also you can check the docs here https://reactrouter.com/web/api/matchPath

Answer (score 1):

You can use useEffect hook to implement the side effect that you want.

First, you can put "location" variable as one of the dependencies inside useEffect hook as below.

```
useEffect(() => {

// do your if condition
// set isView state as side effect

},[location]);
```

Secondly, I believe your condition is not correct.

location.pathname will not equal to '/items/:itemId' since **:itemId** is a dynamic parameter. So, you have an option to use includes method to check if it is your url or you  can add a wrapper which will resolve to "/items" first , then to "/items/:itemId". When the route comes into the wrapper, you can do the styling.

EDIT: or better yet you can use matchPath api of react-router as @ludwiguer has mentioned also to match your path.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @Kevin Moe Myint Myat in his answer. Your condition is not correct as it contains a dynamic id in it. So you can check for `/items` using includes method and if `this.props.match` is available, then you can use it to check if param itemId is present or not. Like `this.props.match.params.itemId`, you can use this with previous condition with AND `&` operator in useEffect.