# How to update state in useeffect based on url using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to change right property from 16px to 40px when user is in page "/items/:itemId" using react and typescript.

below is my component snippet,

```
const root = () => {
    <PopupContextProvider>
        <App/>
    </PopupContextProvider>
}


export const PopupContextProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    return (
        <popupContext.Provider value={context}>
            {children}
            {(condition1 || condition2) && (
                <Popup onHide={dismiss} />
            )}
        </popupContext.Provider>
    );
}

export function Popup({ onHide }: Props) {
    const location = useLocation();
    const [isView, setIsView] = React.useState(false);
    if (location.pathname === '/items/:itemId') {
        setIsView(true);//here doesnt change to true. how can i do the same 
        //in useeffect or something that updates 
    }
    return (
        <Dialog isView={isView}>
            <DialogBody>
                <span>Title</span>
                <Description/>
            </DialogBody>
            <Actions>
                <span>Hide</span>
            </Actions>
        </Dialog>
    );
}


const Dialog = styled.div<isView?:boolean>`
    position: fixed;
    ${({ isView }) => isView && 'right:  40px;'}
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
`;
```

In the above snippet, i check for location and update the isView state to true.

now even when user is in page "/items/:itemId" the isView is not updated from false to true.

how can i update state in useeffect???

could someone help me with this? thanks .

Comment: This same question has been asked already.
Head to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63006417/how-to-set-state-in-useeffect-hook-using-react-and-typescript/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the isView state at all, just make it a `const`.

```js
export function Popup({ onHide }: Props) {
    const location = useLocation();
    const isView = location.pathname === '/items/:itemId';
    return (
        <Dialog isView={isView}>
            <DialogBody>
                <span>Title</span>
                <Description/>
            </DialogBody>
            <Actions>
                <span>Hide</span>
            </Actions>
        </Dialog>
    );
}
```

State is only needed if you need to remember something that does change, like the user entering information or clicking a button, when React rerenders the component. But, in this case you probably aren't changing the path without reloading the page and getting a new instance of your component.

If you really want to use `useEffect` you can just put an empty array as the second arg which means it will only run when the component is created just like `componentDidMount` in class React.

```js
export function Popup({ onHide }: Props) {
    const location = useLocation();
    const [isView, setIsView] = React.useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (location.pathname === '/items/:itemId') {
            setIsView(true);//here doesnt change to true. how can i do the same 
            //in useeffect or something that updates 
        }
    }, []);
    return (
        <Dialog isView={isView}>
            <DialogBody>
                <span>Title</span>
                <Description/>
            </DialogBody>
            <Actions>
                <span>Hide</span>
            </Actions>
        </Dialog>
    );
}
```

You might get a warning that you need to add `isView` into the empty array at the end. React wants you to watch the values you are modifying and call `useEffect` when they change. You can add it but it is weird because it will never change.

You could store `isView` in a `ref` then you wouldn't get the warning because ref updates do not cause a rerender, but again there is no reason to store this variable for rerenders it can be calculated quickly and easily.

Comment: thanks is it still okay to use location.pathname for dynamic values like in this path "/items/:itemId" here itemId can be any number.

Comment: Here for the first time the popup mounts in page "/items" on clicking a button in that page. now when user navigates to "/items/:itemId" i want to check this url. for some reason the isView doesnt update either in useeffect too. could you please help me. i am trying this from one day now.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change `isView` when the location changes? That should happen from the `useLocation` call.